# Changing the background of selected row using jquery or javascript

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I am trying to change the background color of selected row once the checkbox of that row is selected.
i am using knockout js., and below function is for click of that checkbox.

```
 self.checkBoxChecked = function (data, event) {
                if (event.currentTarget.checked) {
                    self.EmailDetailsList.push(data);
                    $(this).toggleClass("highlight");
                } else {
                    self.EmailDetailsList.pop(data);
                }
                console.log(data);
                return true;
            };
```

Please let me know whether i am doing it right.

Comment: plz give a working jsfiddle of this code implementation.

Comment: I disagree with closing this question as off-topic. Although he could have supplied more information, he stated the desired behavior (change the background of a table row) and he showed the relevant part of his code. Maybe the people who downvoted did not read carefully enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this i got a solution,

```
 self.checkBoxChecked = function (data, event) {
            if (event.currentTarget.checked) {
                self.EmailDetailsList.push(data);
                event.currentTarget.parentElement.parentElement.className = 'highlightRow';
                self.isSelected(true);
            }
            else {
                self.EmailDetailsList.pop(data);
                event.currentTarget.parentElement.parentElement.className = '';
                self.isSelected(false);
            }
        console.log(data);
        return true;
    }
```

Since i will be getting the row info from my html page, i will just find its parent root and add a class for it. this solved my issue.:)

Answer (score 0):

There's not enough code here to tell exactly what you are doing, but basically no, if you're using knockout you are not doing it right. The idea of knockout is to avoid manipulating the DOM in code, as in $(this).toggleClass("highlight"), and instead setup bindings between the viewmodel and the DOM properties you want to control. Then you manipulate your viewmodel and let knockout do its job.

For this type of thing you would want to add a property to data, for example data.isSelected, make it an observable, and on the `<tr>` tag for the row you would add:

```
data-bind="css: { 'highlight': isSelected }"
```

In the checkbox event handler you would set data.isSelected(true), and knockout would set the highlight property on the `<tr>`.

Comment: Ya i did the same what you have told, its working fine, thanks, but a small issue, since the binding, html binding is inside loop, i guess it is applying to all the tr.

Comment: What does your binding look like? If you use a knockout foreach binding then each tr will use the one data object it is bound to. The highlighting will not apply to all the tr.